# ModuleNotFound: tensorflow Running Docker Jupyter OSX

Tags: macos, docker, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook

After installing docker, I attempted to run tensorflow in Jupyter.  My run command was

```sh
LewIss-MacBook-Pro:MyTensorFlow lewleib$  docker run -it -p 8888:8888 -p 6006:6006 -v ~/Users/lewleib/MyTensorFlow:/notebooks tensorflow/tensorflow
```

In the Jupyter notebook I ran

```py
import tensorflow as tf
hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
sess = tf.Session()
print(sess.run(hello)
```

This resulted in

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'

I have tried starting in different directories and added prefix gcr.io with the same results.  Thanks

Comment: Works fine for me, same command https://i.stack.imgur.com/DlS05.png

Comment: Thanks.  Any suggestions on what I can check?